# Express Router works for GET but not for POST methods

Tags: express, router

Router JS file.
This a fragment of a long Router but I extracted the relevant part.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Parsers for POST data
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The following POST returns 404 (Not Found).

```
router.post('/job-notify', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("NNN")
    console.log("NNN")
    next()
});
```

The following GET works fine.

```
router.get('/job-appl-monitor', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("MMM")
    res.send("MMM")
    next()
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How do you call your POST endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the `node.js` process or are you using `nodemon` most of the times that this happens to me I forgot to restart the server :-).

Nodemon docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: Hi Lars, yes I am running nodemon, and GET method is working fine.

Comment: Okay then, do you add the `Router` on the `Application`? The code you are using for the POST looks completely fine to me.

Comment: Yup, otherwise the GET method will not work. const jobs = require('./routes/jobs'); app.use('/', jobs);

Comment: Is your method `POST` in your client?

Comment: Hi Lars, I tested the request from Postman for POST, it returns status 200 OK? But not from the browser!

Comment: @فوزيالصويملFawziAlswaimil From the browser? What are you doing exactly? If you call your endpoint via the browser bar it's going to be a GET request.

Comment: Hi Lars, this how it's sent from Express:                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="/api/job/job-submit/<%=job[0].ejsJobCode%>?clang=<%=clang%>"><%= __('Submit') %></a></p>
                    </div>

Comment: That is a GET request, when connecting to a web page. Try using a the `fetch` api.  So write a function that gets called by a button with a fetch(body, { method: "POST" }); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Hi Lars, It was my mistake, the POST request was not working because I was using an href tag rather than a button. Thanks a million.

Comment: No problem, can you please select my answer as the right one. I want my points :-P